# Phonegap load InAppBrowser and url change

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am a newbie when it comes to `Phonegap` development. I have been working on it for couple of days now to have a simple application which opens up an url within app using [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html). I have come up with following code which successfully loads the page i am trying to show within the app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/index.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<title>Riderunner</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

                    // Wait for Cordova to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    var ref= null;

    function iabLoadStart(event) {
            alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    }

    function iabLoadStop(event) {
        alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    }

    // Cordova is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
         ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_self', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
    }

</script>

</head>
<body onload="onDeviceReady()">
</body>
</html>
```

Now what the problem i am facing is `loadstart` event does not trigger. What i mean with that is the alert i have put up in its listener does not popup. Secondly i want to know that while working within the InAppBrowser can we detect the url change or is there any event to detect the url ? I want to open some specific url in device browser (user chosen) else display them within app.
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Change `ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_self', 'location=yes');` to

```
 ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

No need to call onDeviceReady() on body onload.

Comment: removed the onload from body, now nothing displayed.

Comment: how can i check if the url is changed ? i mean i want to use _blank parameter when some part (substring) of a url is matched ?

Comment: Hope you have a cordova.js file in your js folder. 
I made three changes and it worked.  
1)Added exact cordova path. 
2)_blank instead of _self.
3) Removed onload="onDeviceReady()"

Comment: I copied the cordova.js file from phonegap archive to the js directory. Removed the onDeviceReady from onload() and replaced _self with _blank. Still the event does not trigger.

Comment: can you send me the cordova.js you are using which is working ?

Comment: which version are you using? Used 2.7.0.

Comment: i have 3.0.1 set in config.xml

Comment: I haven't checked inAppBrowser in Cordova-3+. But I can't see any major changes in phonegap documents. Hope u add <feature name="InAppBrowser"> and <param name -- >in config.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please try with the below code it will always capture event if url is changed in your browser :-
    ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
 ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {   
                      var URL=event.url;
                      var n = URL.startsWith("http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                     if(n==true){
                         iabRef.close();
                         // root reload
                     }
                  });
```